# Console - WinAPI - Colors

Tags: c++, winapi, terminal, console

what's the best way to paint a line/row of a colour in the windows terminal?
Are there only green, red and blue colours?
I've seen people looping through every possition of the line, is this the best behaviour?

Comment: I think the console only provides 16 colors, and even to get those you need to make some special API calls. You can see the full list here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You should not be using anything "graphical" in console, because GUI is not done in the console, and console is not meant to be used that way. Make a Windows application instead.

Comment: However there are things like nCurses, and I need an interface like that. I didn't really want to go for ncurses though..

Answer (score 3):

Use a [Console Screen Buffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088.aspx) to specify background/foreground colors and positioning for text output.